# Achieving normal volume for '\a' output from C program on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows

I have written a simple C program that outputs '\a' to the standard output via printf(). I have compiled it with gcc under Cygwin on a PC running Windows 7. The sound I hear when I execute the program is a VERY faint version of the one of the usual Windows alert sounds (it sounds like a chord being struck on some kind of musical instrument). But I cannot get a sound that has the usual volume of this sound. Is there a way to get that volume?

Comment: Are you looking for [MessageBeep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356\(v=vs.85\).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Output '\a' with printf() normaly outputs a beep through the integrated pc-speaker. To play a veep via the soundcard use [MessageBeep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the WinAPI.

For example:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. The sound from '\a' is definitely coming from my actual speakers. When I use your proposed solution, the sound produced changes, but the volume is the same.

Comment: Some PCs especially notebooks play the beep-sound via the normal speakers. But my solution should play with the same volume as the normal Windows alert sounds. Which depend on your volume setting in Windows.

Comment: My computer is an ordinary Dell desktop. I have played with the volume settings I know about, but there might be others buried in the Windows option swamp. With the current settings, your solution generates the same faint sound as '\a'.

Comment: On my notebook and my desktop the sound of `MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
` differs completly from `printf("\a");`. Maybe you have a problem with your soundcard? From the MessageBeep documentation: _"If it cannot play the specified alert sound, MessageBeep attempts to play the system default sound. If it cannot play the system default sound, the function produces a standard beep sound through the computer speaker."_